# Error while executing an command in discord.js: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot in javascript using node.js
i'm trying to make the bot disconnect from voice chat, and the following error appears.

```
(node:7324) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at Object.module.exports.run (C:\Users\Edd\Desktop\BlueHoleBot\commands\leavevc.js:10:11)
    at Client.bot.on (C:\Users\Edd\Desktop\BlueHoleBot\BHB.js:44:33)
    at Client.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\Edd\Desktop\BlueHoleBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\Edd\Desktop\BlueHoleBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\Edd\Desktop\BlueHoleBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\Edd\Desktop\BlueHoleBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Edd\Desktop\BlueHoleBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Receiver._receiver.onmessage (C:\Users\Edd\Desktop\BlueHoleBot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:137:47)
(node:7324) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7324) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

i've tried rewriting the code multiple times, deleting the file, looking for references on the discord.js website and no matter what i still write, the same error appears.

```
const Discord = require ("discord.js")

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  if (!message.guild) return;

    // Only try to join the sender's voice channel if they are in one themselves
    if (message.member.voiceChannel) {
      if (message.member.voiceChannel) {
        message.member.voiceChannel.leave()
          .then(connection => { // Connection is an instance of VoiceConnection
            message.reply('I have successfully disconnected to the channel!');
            console.log("disconnected.")
        })
        .catch(console.log);
    } else {
      message.reply("Not connected to any voice channel.");
    }
}}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "leave"
}
```

Comment: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=leave

Comment: if i add ; it still throws the same error.

Comment: The important information in the docs is `Returns: void`. You can't call `then` on `leave()`.

Comment: Fixed it: removed .then and .catch 
Thanks for the answer!